# グローバルIPアドレスでWebサーバ、Apache2.4に接続できません。

Tags: apache

Apache2.4をWindows10proにインストールして、ローカルIPアドレス、80番ポートでApache2.4を立ち上げ、ルーターで、静的IPマスカレード設定で、変換対象プロトコル・TCP、変換対象ポートwww(80)、宛先IPアドレス・192.168.1.18、宛先ポート・www（80）で設定し、IPv4パケットフィルタ設定を規制全部解除して、Windows Firewallのドメインネットワーク、プライベートネットワーク、パブリックネットワークの機能を停止させ、ウィルスバスタークラウドのWebサイト例外接続許可設定もし、リアルタイムスキャンも機能OFFにしましたが。

どうすれば、いいでしょうか？

Comment: こういうトラブルシューティングは実機を前にしていろいろ試すことができないと困難です。とりあえず Web UA をどこで起動しどう接続したかも必要っす。ひとまず、 Apache httpd がちゃんと動作するか LAN 内部からチェックしましたか？　あと Windows10 pro を汎用サーバー目的に使うと EULA 違反になるっす。

Comment: ドコモ光の戸建てタイプでプロバイダはOCNです。IPv6接続を解除したり、静的IPマスカレード設定を一度解除して、簡易DMZ設定機能、でルータに届いたパケット全部、Apache2.4のPCに転送させたりしましたが、だめでした。

Comment: kizu1023 さんは質問者さんと同じ方でしょうか？　もしそうであれば、アカウントがふたつに分かれてしまっているため[アカウントの統合をお試しください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)。質問したアカウントであれば質問文に直接追記できます。読みやすさのため、情報を追加する際は質問文を直接編集していただく形になります。

Comment: @kizu1023 さん、既に解決なさったかもしれませんが、追加情報のようなものが書かれた投稿を一時的な処置として回答ではなくコメントに移しました。もし質問者さんご本人であれば、質問文の方に移しますのでアカウントを統合していただけるとありがたいです。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

自宅のネットワークから、物理的にはなれ、外出先から、ドコモのスマホで4GでApacheを参照したら、ちゃんとHTML文書が参照できました。お手数おかけいたしました、

Comment: 「グローバルIPアドレス」≠「宛先IPアドレス・192.168.1.18」ですけど、どういうことですか？

Answer (score -2):

あなたんちの回線は何でしょうか。
光のマンションタイプとか、CATV回線なんかは、プライペートIPしか配布されないのでサーバ公開は無理になります